# bash: how to sum up spaced number from read command?

Tags: printf, echo, user-input, calc

for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '%s' "write 4 numbers separated by spaces:"

read -r var

# suppose to print sum of calculated numbers, in this case I want to calculate like this:
# ((1n*2n)+(3n*4n))/2 <----divided by (total item/2)

exit 0
```

so, lets say we put 4 numbers when we execute the code, lets put `11 22 33 44.4`, and then `enter`, after that we got `853.6` as the result if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is lacking built-in support for calculations with *real* numbers but there are lots of [options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/391809).

From that long list I picked [bc](/questions/tagged/bc) since it's the one I'm comfortable with:

```
#!/bin/bash

wanted_numbers=4
read -p "write ${wanted_numbers} numbers separated by spaces: " line
#echo "debug: line >$line<" >&2

result=0
numbers=0

while read var
do
    #echo "debug: got >$var<" >&2
    result=$(bc <<< "${result}+${var}")
    numbers=$((numbers + 1))
done < <(tr ' ' '\n' <<< $line)

if [[ $numbers != $wanted_numbers ]]; then
    echo "I asked for ${wanted_numbers} numbers and got ${numbers}. Try again..." >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo $result
```

From here on you can do whatever you need to do with `${result}`. If you need to do division with *real* numbers, [bc](/questions/tagged/bc) is your friend.

The trickiest part in this is the [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) that you see in `done < <(...)` to be able to set variables in the `while` loop, in what would otherwise be a subshell, and have the result available outside the loop.

Comment: hi again @TedLyngmo my friend, I got one more advance answer from you, I actually did it my self in rough way, but this answer proves its level one step ahead. cant wait to test it tomorrow.

Comment: @AhiungLim Oh, I didn't notice that we just solved a problem together earlier. I hope this one works out too! :-)

Comment: my friend, your answer worked out perfectly, but it is limited to just 4 or pre-described numbers. but it's okay because my post didn't say `any` numbers, and that answered my initial question. It just surprised me for seeing something very new to me like the `#echo` thing, i thought that part is a comment, but it's not, and i dont know how is that work out. my version of calculating spaced numbers is [here](https://textbin.net/bsm5cSDwT5), I used array technique and other basic stuffs to make it happen.

Comment: @AhiungLim I sometimes put code in `#comments` in my answers if I feel that it may provide some additional info if uncommented. Just remove all lines (except the first) starting with `#`.

 Yes it works according to "`write 4 numbers`". Did I misunderstand that part?

Comment: ah i see now that's a code but commented out  because it just needed when testing the value, i thought that whole lines is doing something else, but silly me. you did not misubderstand anything it just the way I explain wasnt whole. see you in the next problem my friend, have a good day.